# How do I change the mvc 4 account to use MSSQL instead of sqlexpress for users

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, sql-server-2008

This is the default connectionstring

```
<!--<add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />-->
```

I now have this connectionstring (Removed the url parts)

```
<add name="madsskipper_dk_dbEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Areas.Units.UnitsModel.csdl|res://*/Areas.Units.UnitsModel.ssdl|res://*/Areas.Units.UnitsModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;
```

What I then want is to make the inbuild is to use my own database for this (So it also works deployed) but just changing the connectionStringName="madsskipper_dk_dbEntities" dont help, I just get a

> Argument Exception {"Unable to find the requested .Net Framework Data Provider.  It may not be installed."}

```
    <profile defaultProvider="DefaultProfileProvider">
  <providers>
    <add name="DefaultProfileProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultProfileProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="madsskipper_dk_dbEntities" applicationName="/"/>
  </providers>
</profile>
<membership defaultProvider="DefaultMembershipProvider">
  <providers>
    <add name="DefaultMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultMembershipProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="madsskipper_dk_dbEntities" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="false" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="6" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="10" applicationName="/"/>
  </providers>
</membership>
<roleManager defaultProvider="DefaultRoleProvider">
  <providers>
    <add name="DefaultRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultRoleProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="madsskipper_dk_dbEntities" applicationName="/"/>
  </providers>
</roleManager>
<sessionState mode="InProc" customProvider="DefaultSessionProvider">
  <providers>
    <add name="DefaultSessionProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultSessionStateProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="madsskipper_dk_dbEntities" applicationName="/"/>
  </providers>
</sessionState>
```

Edit: I think I need to add something like this (Just with SQL 2008 instead of SQL Lite)

```
<system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories>
        <remove invariant="System.Data.SQLite"/>
        <add name="SQLite Data Provider" invariant="System.Data.SQLite" description=".Net Framework Data Provider for SQLite" type="System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteFactory, System.Data.SQLite"/>
    </DbProviderFactories>
</system.data>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Create somewhere text file with extension .udl (e.g. 1.udl)
2. in explorer double-click it.
3. Fill all necessarily fields on all tabs starting from provider (ensure and locate SQL server)
4. Test connection and close this by 'Ok'.
5. Open 1.udl by notepad and copy result string to your config file

Comment: Isnt this just to make a connectionstring? I want to those "<membership defaultProvider="DefaultMembershipProvider">" etc work? My current connectionstring works fine

Comment: @Mech0z hmm, from error: "Unable to find the requested .Net Framework Data Provider. It may not be installed." i've deduced that you have wrong connection string. Anyway on our project we have same problem with connection string substitution. We have provided special task on build system - that changed config file right before build.